# System Stoplist empty after installing SQL Server 2016 Express Edition SP1

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2016

I recently installed SQL Server 2016 Express Edition and then applied SP1. But I see my system stoplist empty for fulltext search.

```
Select * from sys.fulltext_stoplists;
```

This does not return any rows. I remember it worked for me in SQL Server 2014 Express Edition.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: ,https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/